# How is melagra described in contemporary English?

Tags: single-word-requests, contemporary-english

The noun MELAGRA stands for rheumatic or myalgic pains in the arms or legs. This is the word I found which is closest to describing the kind of pain that one feels all over the body during fever or sometimes on a rainy day. In my native language, they say something like "my arms are being bitten/eaten away."

How do you say such a thing in English? The word melagra sounds too formal/medical. How do native English-speakers describe the pain that feels like being nibbled on?

Comment: Hello, Nanashi. We'd just say "My legs ache" or "I ache all over", or "I feel like I'm being bitten on my legs". 'Melagra' is not a term I've come across.

Comment: Okay, so 'aching' has no hyponyms in common English?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe headache, stomachache, earache, toothache...

Comment: Giving hyponyms I think you intended: I've heard 'pulsating' for a side-effect of a bisphosphonate. And "My skin's crawling" when that applies. 'Burning' is hardly the same sensation.

Comment: @DanBron Alright, so there are hyponyms based on the location of the pain, but none describing the differences in how they feel?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay, thanks. What does crawling skin mean?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe Like you have bugs on your skin. There’s also piercing pain, dull ache, pins and needles, and a host of others. But I don’t think there’s on that describes leg rheumatism.

Comment: In addition to the good answers, I just want to point out that 'melagra' is very rare. No one uses it nowadays.

Comment: Are you talking about [Fibromyalgia](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/fibromyalgia/symptoms-causes/syc-20354780)?

Comment: @Cascabel That could be one of the many causes of the sensation I am talking about.

Comment: Nanashi, we need to know what hurts (skin?  bones?  muscles?  etc.), and we need to know when it hurts (occasional sharp pain?  dull chronic pain?  etc.) and we need to know the nature of the pain (steady, pulsating, stabbing, unbearable, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I would favor a compound that identifies the kind of thing being affected:

- **muscle pain** or **joint pain** or **back pain**
- **aching muscles** or **aching joints** or **aching back**

Expressions for pain tend to be fairly literal in English. A specific example is **to feel it in (one's) bones**, with **it** literally referring to a storm or another weather pattern. (See "[Can You Really *Feel a Storm Coming in Your Bones*?](https://curiosity.com/topics/can-you-really-feel-a-storm-coming-in-your-bones-curiosity/)") The *feeling* is a general ache that arthritis sufferers feel when the barometric pressure changes. In this case, the expression has spawned an idiom that more generally means *intuition*. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/feel-it-in-your-bones):

> *feel it in your bones*
>
> to believe something strongly although you cannot explain why:

More generally, to capture the experience of great pain, especially over an entire body or area, **racked with pain** (or **racked** taking the part affected as the object) is a common expression. From the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/rack_2#rack_inflg_1):

> (also less frequent wrack) [often passive] rack somebody/something to make somebody suffer great physical or mental pain
>
> to be racked with/by guilt
>
> Her face was **racked with pain**.
>
> Violent sobs **racked her whole body.**
>
> (British English) a racking cough

If someone is bedridden from pain or if their pain is particularly visible (periodic shuddering, groans, facial expressions), they may be **racked with pain**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for a word that captures the sensation more elaborately, rather than the intensity of the pain.

Comment: "I feel it in my bones" literally refers to feeling an ache come on before a rain shower, but as an idiom it pertains more widely to intuitive knowledge, c.f. gut feelings. Is that more of what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's very close. I guess "My skin's crawling" is also close, if I understood that correctly.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe "Skin is crawling" has a different connotation...it usually refers to a physiological reaction to something icky or scary.

Answer (score 1):

The feeling of *[pins and needles](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pins-and-needles)* when your leg or arm has fallen asleep, and circulation is returning, might capture what you're looking for.

However, a whole-body pain of the sort you're describing is best captured by *[formication](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/321896.php)*: "the sensation of having insects crawling on or under the skin."

Comment: “Formication”? And where have you ever heard anyone say that? Sure you don’t mean “fornication”? Too much of that can tire you out.